How to run commands from Python console with the same config as Pycharm Terminal
Is there a quick/practical way to run commands from the Pycharm Python console with exactly the same configurations as Pycharm Terminal?
I.e. I am able to run certain software like wget from Pycharm's terminal but not from the python console os.system("wget") which gives me a "wget is not recognized..."
I know there are other ways to achieve the same thing as wget but I'm only interested in knowing if there is a quick/practical way to configure it so that I get the same experience running system commands from python console as from the terminal.
It's fine if it's not done through the os package specifically, but I need to get to a point where I can execute terminal commands exactly the same from terminal & python console.

the python console runs python commands.. You could use sys.subprocess for example to run a windows command from python

Please let us know what OS you are using.
